# How to Start an application during boot without login in Linux-Yocto

Tags: linux, yocto

I am currently trying to deploy an image on my raspberry pi 3 that would allow me to run a simple "helloworld" application after boot. I want my board to display the helloworld text without me needing to login with root id. I am using systemd and have already tried solutions such as appending the "-a root" command in systemd/serial-getty@service file. Can anyone provide a solution for this?

Comment: You are talking about a lots of different things here. Are you trying to deploy an image. Under image do you mean a docker image? Simple helloworld application, do you mean systemd application or docker based application? What do you mean under "board to display", are you using some external display with the pi, or some built in custom LCD module?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I am using a poky reference distribution of Yocto project.

The image I am building is a core-minimal-image using bitbake, containing an application (a .c file) which prints *helloworld* upon execution on the console.

The display I am using is a 5 inch touch panel connected to my raspberry pi.

I have used a *systemd* service to execute the application after the boot process, however I have to login as **root** in order to actually execute the service/application and I want to bypass this step.

How do i have to specify the service, so that it starts automatically without logon?